# XML with several levels to Dataset with XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xmldocument

I have this xml file with several levels for node's childs:

```
-product
--name
--price
--made
-----product
--------name
--distributor
-----name
------address
/product
```

I need to read it in sequence, but it's not possible with XmlReader, so I have to use XmlDocument to read each node and copy into DataSet (or similar).
How can I read node by node and copy to dataset in C# ??? Any help please?

Comment: It is definitely not an XML. Show the actual XML.

Answer (score 1):

Convert xml string to DataSet using `StringReader`

```
string xmlData = "<product><name></name><price></price><made></made></product>";
StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlData);
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
ds.ReadXml(reader);
```

Write XML Data into a DataSet directly from xml file:

```
string myfile = @"C:\myXml.xml";
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(myfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Xpath over XMl Document to read node by node.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using `XDocument` and `LINQ-to-XML`:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
// Create two DataTable instances.
DataTable table1 = new DataTable("patients");
table1.Columns.Add("name"); 

foreach(var name in doc.Root.DescendantNodes().OfType<XElement>()
        .Select(x => x.Name).Distinct())
{
    table1.Rows.Add(name);
    Console.WriteLine(name);       
}
```